# Connecting mininet to a Open vSwitch in different computers

Tags: mininet, openvswitch

I have 3 different machines with Controller (Onos), an switch (Open vSwitch) and one with mininet and I have been looking how to connect mininet hosts to a switch outside of the machine running mininet to generate traffic to test a few things in OvS. Not sure if I used the wrong terms but I could not find anything on the topic.

(tl;dr)

Is it possible to connect mininet hosts to switches other than the one created by mininet?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of doing this without modifying mininet itself.

The easiest way to work with this is to know that mininet creates a OvS Switch for easy switch that you declare and you can use the same commands on them outside the mininet terminal.

That was the best solution in my case